# Plugin to speed up embedded videos?

Tags: video, video-streaming, html5

I'm specifically concerned with videos embedded with the `<video>` tag.

I'd like to know if there is a Chrome or Firefox plugin, extension, etc. which can be used to play videos at greater than 100% speed without having to download the whole video, and watch in an external player? Quick googling doesn't turn up anything obvious.

Comment: Since this is about web browser plugins/extensions, rather than a web app, this would be better off on [su].

Comment: I don't think this is possible by browser, maybe through a greasemonkey-script.
Here's a link i just found by google. http://lifehacker.com/5491852/enable-variable-speed-playback-in-youtube

Comment: Umm. You can view the source of the video tag, copy it and paste it into VLC? But you can't speed something up if you have not go the data to do it. Weird question? (Ale co ty chcesz zrobic tak naprwade?)

Comment: @Vanadis If that works, post it as an answer.

Comment: @ppumkin Right, but I can download the video sufficiently fast enough. I do just want to watch the video more quickly, because it is a lecture, and I can absorb the information more quickly.

Comment: Then download the whole movie and use VLC. It can do it